# Plot the number of months (binned) between consecutive purchases and no. of customers falling in each bin in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, plotly

My data looks like below :

```
Customer     Product      Date
C1           P1           2012-01-02
C1           P1           2014-02-21      
C1           P1           2016-05-22
C2           P1           2012-02-20
C2           P1           2013-08-02
C1           P1           2017-06-02
C1           P1           2018-07-11
```

I have to count the no. of months(bins) between two consecutive purchases for each customer and plot a graph between bins and no. of customers falling in each bin .

Ex. of graph in excel is attached. Here x axis represents no of months of consecutive purchase and y axis represents count of customers falling in each bin

Basically steps would be to find average no. of months between two purchases for each customer , bin the number of months and plot the bar graph between the no of months bin and no. of customers falling in each bin.

[image]

Comment: Is it the time difference between purchases for a customer regardless of product, or within product?

Comment: Time difference is within a product . I have 8 different products for which I have to build a chart for each product

Answer (score 0):

"Month" is a variable amount of time lasting between 28 to 31 days. For our analysis, let's define a month as being equivalent to 30 days. You can then use `pd.cut` to bin them and make a histogram:

```
s = df.sort_values(['Customer', 'Date']) \
      .groupby('Customer').apply(lambda g: g['Date'].diff().div(pd.Timedelta(days=30)).mean())

t = pd.cut(s, [10, 15, 20, 30, np.inf], labels=['10-15M', '15-20M', '20-30M', '>30M'])
t.hist()
```

Result (both customers in your example fall into the `15-20M` bin):

[image: Purchase Frequency]